# Communication between Python desktop app and remote Django server

Tags: python, django, sockets, client, django-channels

Would it be possible to have two-way communication between a Python desktop application and a Django server, and if so what would be the best method? The Django server would host a page that allows a user to send commands to the desktop application and view the status of the desktop application. The desktop app would need to send status updates.

I've looked into Channels with Django and the client would just need to create a TCP socket connection to send its data. I don't quite know how Django would send the required data to the client.

Thanks for any help or input.

Comment: Your app is kind of "subscribed" to a channel. When someone sends some data to that channel, then every client subscribed to it will be signaled about new data arrival.

Comment: I see, it's like an event system. So would the clients need to connect to an ip and port on that channel to send and receive data?

Comment: Javascript on the client side in page template is responsible for establishing a connection and send and receive data to and from server. So a simple visit to a defined url activates the mechanism.

Comment: So then the same idea would apply to the desktop application connecting to the Django server?

Comment: Yep, by Webkit Python port or so. However, it should be possible to implement a client in Python without browser supporting Javascript. For such a question either Google search or ask in djabgo-channels Google group.

Comment: I will make sure to, thank you for the recommendations.